# File format that is simple like XML but smaller

Tags: xml, file-format

I'm creating a map editor that saves maps for something.  Currently, I've been saving it in XML (because it is built into the .net framework).  The problem is, XML is very bloated and there could be thousands of elements per file.

Is there any other simple to use formats (that I don't have to create a complicated parser for) to can store just some simple values?

Comment: Did you even try to google this? There are lots of formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at JSON http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
or protobuf http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/.
For both formats .NET libraries exists.

Comment: JSON looks pretty simple and nice.  I'll probably go with it.  Thanks :)